# How to use async data for use with chart.js in ionic

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, promise, chart.js

I am calling some data in via an api for an ionic app I'm making. The data is being called asynchronously and I need to assign the data to different variables for use in a chart that gets presented to the user. I'm struggling to assign the data to a variable that I can then access from the function which creates the chart (I'm using chart.js). Initially I've been trying to grab a list of dates from the data for use as the X axis scale, just to get things working.

Been trying quite a few things and failing. I initially thought it was because my variable was block scoped, but now I think its an async issue. Been reading about promises for hours, but although I understand the concept I can't see away to apply it to my current code (presuming the issue is async! I'm a noob on a self teaching mission here).

So this the code which handles pulling in the data from the api

```
async getData() {
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Loading'
  });
  await loading.present();
  this.api.getData()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.data1 = res[0];
      loading.dismiss();
      console.log(this.data1);

    const datelabel = this.data1.result[1].date;

    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      loading.dismiss();
    }); 

}
```

And this is the code which creates the chart

```
useAnotherOneWithWebpack() {

    var ctx = (<any>document.getElementById('canvas-linechart')).getContext('2d');
    console.log('GotData', this.datelabel); //just to see what data I've got here if any in the console

    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: this.datelabel,
            datasets: [{ 
                data: [86,114,106],
                label: "Africa",
                borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                fill: false
              }, { 
                data: [282,350,411],
                label: "Asia",
                borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
                fill: false
              }, { 
                data: [168,170,178],
                label: "Europe",
                borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                fill: false
              }
            ]
          },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
        }
      }
    });

}
```

So I'm calling the datalabel variable against labels, but its displaying as undefined on the axis and in the console. I'm expecting to see three months (which are saved as strings in the variable). Tried all sorts now and its driving me a bit mad. I'm not even sure its an async issue, but from what I've done so far it feels like the issue.

Any help really appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure when/where you're calling the `useAnotherOneWithWebpack()` method but one issue from your code is that you're assigning some values to the **local** constant `datelabel` but not to the property from the component:

```
// The following line just creates a local const available only in that scope
const datelabel = this.data1.result[1].date;
```

Instead, you should be initializing the component's property:

```
this.datelabel = this.data1.result[1].date;
```

Keeping that in mind, please try the following:

```
async getData() {

  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Loading'
  });

  await loading.present();

  this.api.getData().subscribe(
    res => {

      // This line will be executed when getData finishes with a success response
      console.log('Inside of the subscribe - success');

      console.log(res);

      this.data1 = res[0];
      this.datelabel = this.data1.result[1].date;

      // Now that the data is ready, you can build the chart
      this.useAnotherOneWithWebpack();

      loading.dismiss();

    }, 
    err => {

      // This line will be executed when getData finishes with an error response
      console.log('Inside of the subscribe - error');

      console.log(err);

      loading.dismiss();
    }); 


  // This line will be executed without waiting for the getData async method to be finished
  console.log('Outside of the subscribe');

}
```

Comment: Thank you @sebaferreras I really think that might have solved it. Only question is I have a console.log in useAnotherOneWithWebpack for this.datelabel and its shows twice. First time undefined and second time containing the data, presume something to do with async, what triggers it to update? Is it this.useAnotherOneWithWebpack(); or is the just standard behavior?

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working! Hmm, if you're calling that method only once, that console log should be executed only once as well. Could you please add that code to your question to see if there's something going on?

Comment: Its working perfectly pulling in the labels for my x-axis so I'm not too bothered, again thank you. The console log that returns twice is the one in anotheronewithwebpack from my original code. But I'm feeling a bit "if it ain't broke don't fix it" seeing as its now working